# Redux-Toolkit, Firestore- Field section in firestore empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create a collection in firestore, but the field section inside firestore comes out empty. The collection i.e 'user' and doc i.e 'email' section is created, but with 'field' section corresponding to the doc 'email' empty(it must show **watchList:[]**.
I want the setDoc function to store the watchlist(corresponding to different emails). I want this to happen when the user signsIn.
Please help.
Thank you

````
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      navigate("/account");
      console.log(result);
      dispatch(
        storeUser({
          email: result.user.email,
        })
      );
      return await setDoc(doc(db, "users", email), {
        watchList: [],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the dispatch is also running asynchronously. If that is the case, you can use the `result.user.email` value in the database call too:

```
  return await setDoc(doc(db, "users", result.user.email), {
    watchList: [],
  });
```

Comment: Well, I've the email portion visible(i.e the document email corresponding to the 'users' collection. Would it work if I put the adddoc outside the try catch block(with await offcourse)? I guess I don't fully understand how to incorporate multiple functions with redux-toolkit.

Comment: I'm not a Redux user, but expect that you'd have to react to the asynchronous setter. But did you try the code in my answer though? Did the `setDoc` call work with that? If not, were there any errors?